# Why are most famous (or wish fulfiling) temples situated on hills?

Tags: temple

We generally feel that that a temple near our house is a normal temple while that on a particular hill is a special temple (may be because of some story behind it) and those on hill tops are said to be more wish fulfilling ones than the local ones.

Reaching these distance wise and altitude wise far off places must have been all the more difficult in the times for the devotees when they were made than now.

It would have been even more difficult for the creators to get all the material gathered there. So, my question is why are the most famous temples situated on hills which are difficult to visit.

Comment: `difficult to visit...!!!!` do you think you will find `The God` easily ?

Comment: God can be anywhere and everywhere, so why special importance to these. These could have been built at places where people normally live so it would be easily accessible for the devotees. Also, it would have been easy to create in lower level areas as all the materials, etc would be easily available but still they were made at such places. I want to know the reasoning behind these or what actually the creaters must have in their minds choosing that place.

Comment: one potential reasoning behind this: hills are usually isolated and away from big cities. therefore when one makes a pilgrimage to such places, he is temporarily plugs the busy city life and his responsibilities back home. therefore he obtains great rewards by being able to concentrate on the Lord at the temple. Great peace of mind is generated.Temples built in the village/city do not have the exact effect, because one goes there for a short duration (an hour or so) and then has to return back to his busy routine life. Hill temples require pilgrimages, which allows one to contemplate IshtaDeva

Comment: @Sai but why only areas with greater altitude, why not an a lonely place which is on leveled ground or may be some island, there also people can concentrate and will be away from their homes.

Comment: I suppose feasibility of having so many priests and catering to their needs in say a jungle or a distant unpopulated island is much more difficult than a hill or mountain where daily needs can be met easily without living on grass and tubers. Yes from a temple visitor perspective it would be great but from an management perspective not so much. But in this point Im just speculating. perhaps there is a deeper reasoning behind it. better answers can be expected below

Comment: @Sai, island doesn't mean that it won't be having any vegetation, and on hills also everything has to be arranged. Even, the priests and alll other building material could also have to be relocated from the normal places.

Comment: yes there would be difficulties in both types. but I think island would require 1. arranging a boat to get items across, 2. arranging boats for people to get across everyday in hundreds, 3. arranging other temple related stuff to  traverse. Whereas a hill or mountain is something people can get to on foot, maybe in a day or two, without relying on external factors. Just a thought as I said. So hundreds of people can go everyday to say Pazhani or Thirupathi or Sabari mala. not necessarily hundreds can be transported everyday to say an island (and brought back if needed)

Comment: Just a thought...Are hills near to some Celestial/God's place? Remember Pandavs went on to Himalyas to directly enter into Heaven. Is that the way nearer to Heaven. Many Rishi/Munis also go to mountains to do the penance. Is that the place from where God can hear them more clearly?

Comment: As @Kedarnath said, you'll find them quite difficult to visit at the same time, Lord will be pleased very much because he will feel that his devotee has taken that difficulty to come to the hill to see him and he wishfully grants the desires.

Answer (score 1):

Its for multiple reasons.

Religious Reasons :

1. It takes effort from individual to reach their, thus *reducing their sins*.
2. Any form of festival/prayer *gets loud attentions*.
3. When there's some special occasion like *Poornima*, *Ammavasya*, they are represented by using specialized flag to make local public aware from distance.

Scientific Reason :

1. They cosmic energy level is *high* on this altitude.
2. *Aura* (If you understand this term) at such altitudes is very positive.
3. Atmosphere is much clean.

Comment: @GovindChauhan What can be done using the Cosmic energy or Aura received by the temple. Cosmic energy can be both positive as well as negative. So, in case by mistake a negative energy is received then it would be harmful. Is there any basis such that only positive energy will be received.

Comment: @Aby as far as Aura is concerned, it's always good. However i cannot say the same about Cosmic energy.